# Rationale behind sites' categories

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com, site-categories

Stack Exchange sites are [organized into 6 categories](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

- Technology
- Culture / Recreation
- Life / Arts
- Science
- Business
- Professional

Of these *Technology* and *Science* are quite obvious and clear cut. However, I don't really follow rationale with the rest of them.

- Why are *Culture* and *Recreation* or *Life* and *Arts* bundled together? If it's to not to make too small of a category or not make too many categories, then why aren't *Business* and *Professional* bundled together, given that first one has only 5 sites, and second only 2.
- Why *Culture / Recreation* and *Life / Arts*, and not for example *Culture / Arts* and *Life / Recreation* or any other split?

Comment: Believe me, this has/is being discussed and we will (eventually) come to a better taxonomy. It is not clear what would make a good one, though.

Comment: @Oded: for one, I see 3 clearly distinct, non-overlapping groups in C&R category: games/sports/leisure, languages, religion. BTW. if it's being discussed and you can share some of the insights, that would be answer to this question.

Comment: Sure, but we at Stack Exchange need to think about the future and existing and future beta sites. As for insights - we are at a short supply of those, hence the current state of things...

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), you'll notice there are actually **8** categories<sup>1</sup>:

- **Arts**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like art, humanities, media, literature, and music*</sup>
- **Business**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like management, economics, and markets*</sup>
- **Culture**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like language, religion, society, groups, and politics*</sup>
- **Life**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like home, family, education, careers, and self-improvement*</sup>
- **Professional**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like organizations, occupations, and vocations*</sup>
- **Recreation**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like sports, games, and hobbies*</sup>
- **Science**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like the applied, natural, cognitive, formal, and social sciences*</sup>
- **Technology**
  <sup>*proposals in subjects like computing, technology, gadgets, and electronics*</sup>

It's [best](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1362/5680) to think about these categories as describing the *people* who are the target audience rather than the *subject* of the site.  Obviously there are affinities (scientific people are often technology people too).  However the idea is to group sites in a way that will be broadly of interest to people involved particular social spheres.

When it comes to the organization on Stack Exchange itself, the categories needed to be collapsed in order to fit the graduated sites in the footer.  (See below `vvv`.)  All of the Business and Professional sites are in beta, so those are not included.  Of the remaining categories, Technology is far and away the most populous as you might imagine from our origins.  The challenge was to fit the other categories in the footer in a pleasing way.  Grouping Life with Arts and Culture with Recreation did the trick.  The category grouping is extended to [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) so that when you click the `more (X)` link you will get the same set of sites.

As new sites pass from beta to fully graduated, we'll need to add them into the footer.  That could very well mean that categories are grouped differently.  Certainly if a Business or Professional site graduates, they will need to be added.  Another Culture site or two would probably warrant its own column.

---

1. It's entirely coincidental that there are also [8 Usenet hierarchies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_8_(Usenet)).  There is a fair amount of overlap; Stack Exchange has Business and Professional rather than `misc.*` and `news.*`.

Comment: Workplace has graduated a while ago, but there is still no place for it in the footer (no Professional category there)...